# Installing redhat in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm having trouble installing red hat 6 in VirtualBox on a Fedora 15 host.  As soon as I choose install from the initial menu, I get this kernel error. I can't copy and paste the error so here is a print-screen image.  I'm not even sure what it means, can somebody help?

[image: RedHat Error]

Comment: How did you set up the virtual machine?

Comment: Page fault is to do with memory and it comes after an alloc, did you give it enough memory to use?

Comment: I have it 3 gb of memory so I wouldn't think that would be the issue.  Otherwise it was the default virtualbox setup - 12mb of video memory,8 gb hard drive

Answer (score 0):

Try bumping up the hard drive space. Try for at least 20 - 30GB.

Without seeing your hardware specs it's tough to tell. A Kernel Panic on startup is usually because something broke or you don't have enough disk space, memory, cpu, etc. Since this is a new install I would guess you aren't giving it enough resources.